# A persistent file system operations queue using sqlite and JSON text fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I want to implement a persistent queue for file system operations (copy, delete, move) that needs to be process and thread safe. The module will be used by a daemon (called `qcp`) which can accept `Tasks` from multiple clients. It must also be possible to process several queued elements in parallel.

I am new to python and looking for general advice (even the nitpicky kind) on python best practices and on object-oriented programming in general. I am especially curious if my implementation of `Task.from_json()` as `@staticmethod` is appropriate. I wasn't sure about this because it conditionally instantiates subclasses of `Task` rather than a plain `Task`.

### tasks.py

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Optional
import shutil
import os
import json
import sqlite3    
import logging

Pathish = Union[Path, str]


class Task:
    """Abstract class for qcp Tasks. Should not be instantiated directly."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.type = 0

    def run(self) -> None:
        """Run the Task"""
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(x, validate: bool = False) -> "Task":
        """Create a Task of the appropriate subclass from a python dict"""
        task_type = x["type"]

        if task_type == -1:
            return KillTask()
        elif task_type == 0:
            return Task()
        elif task_type == 1:
            return EchoTask(x["msg"])
        elif task_type == 2:
            return FileTask(x["src"], validate=validate)
        elif task_type == 3:
            return DeleteTask(x["src"], validate=validate)
        elif task_type == 4:
            return CopyTask(x["src"], x["dst"], validate=validate)
        elif task_type == 5:
            return MoveTask(x["src"], x["dst"], validate=validate)
        elif task_type == 6:
            raise NotImplementedError
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return 'NULL'

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __ne__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.__dict__ != other.__dict__


class KillTask(Task):
    """Kill the qcp server"""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.type = -1
        super().__init__()

    def run(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return 'KILL'


class EchoTask(Task):
    """Log a message"""
    def __init__(self,  msg: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.msg = msg
        self.type = 1

    def run(self) -> None:
        print(self.msg)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Echo: "{self.msg}"'


class FileTask(Task):
    """Abstract class for all file-based tasks"""
    def __init__(self, src: Pathish, validate: bool = True) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.validate = validate
        self.src = Path(src).as_posix()
        self.type = 2
        if validate:
            self.__validate__()

    def __validate__(self) -> None:
        if not Path(self.src).exists():
            raise FileNotFoundError(f'{self.src} does not exist')
        elif not (Path(self.src).is_dir() or Path(self.src).is_file()):
            raise TypeError(f'{self.src} is neither a file nor directory')


class DeleteTask(FileTask):
    """Delete a file"""
    def __init__(self, src: Pathish, validate: bool = True) -> None:
        super().__init__(src=src, validate=validate)
        self.type = 3

    def run(self) -> None:
        os.unlink(self.src)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'DEL {self.src}'


class CopyTask(FileTask):
    """Copy a file"""
    def __init__(self, src: Pathish, dst: Pathish, validate: bool = True) -> None:
        super().__init__(src=src, validate=False)
        self.dst = Path(dst).as_posix()
        self.type = 4
        self.validate = validate
        if validate:
            self.__validate__()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'COPY {self.src} -> {self.dst}'

    def __validate__(self) -> None:
        super().__validate__()
        if Path(self.dst).exists():
            raise FileExistsError

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.__validate__()
        shutil.copy(self.src, self.dst)


class MoveTask(CopyTask):
    """Move a file"""
    def __init__(self, src: Pathish, dst: Pathish, validate: bool = True) -> None:
        super().__init__(src=src, dst=dst, validate=validate)
        self.type = 5

    def run(self) -> None:
        super().__validate__()
        shutil.move(self.src, self.dst)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'MOVE {self.src} -> {self.dst}'


class TaskQueueElement:
    """An enqueued Task"""

    task = None  #: A Task
    status = None  #: Status of the queued Task
    priority = None  #: Priority of the queued Task

    def __init__(self, task: Task, priority: 1) -> None:
        self.task = task
        self.priority = priority

    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.priority < other.priority

    def __gt__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.priority > other.priority

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __ne__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.__dict__ != other.__dict__


class TaskQueue:
    """A prioritzed queue for tasks"""
    def __init__(self, path: Pathish = 'qcp.db') -> None:
        """
        Instantiate a TaskQueue

        :param path: Path to store the persistent queue
        :type path: Path or str
        """

        self.con = sqlite3.connect(path, isolation_level="EXCLUSIVE")
        self.path = Path(path)

        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""
           CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
              priority INTEGER,
              task TEXT,
              status INTEGER,
              owner INTEGER              
            )              
        """)
        self.con.commit()

    @property
    def n_total(self) -> int:
        """Count of all tasks in queue (including failed and completed)"""
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        return cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) from tasks").fetchall()[0][0]

    @property
    def n_pending(self) -> int:
        """Number of pending tasks"""
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        return cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tasks WHERE status = 0").fetchall()[0][0]

    @property
    def n_running(self) -> int:
        """Count of currently running tasks"""
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        return cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tasks WHERE status = 1").fetchall()[0][0]

    @property
    def n_done(self) -> int:
        """count of completed tasks"""
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        return cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) from tasks WHERE status = 2").fetchall()[0][0]

    @property
    def n_failed(self) -> int:
        """count of completed tasks"""
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        return cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(1) from tasks WHERE status = -1").fetchall()[0][0]

    def put(self, task: "Task", priority: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        """
        Enqueue a task

        :param task: Task to be added to the queue
        :type task: Task
        :param priority: (optional) priority for executing `task` (tasks with lower priority will be executed earlier)
        :type priority: int
        """

        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO tasks (priority, task, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (priority, json.dumps(task.__dict__), 0)
        )
        self.con.commit()

    def pop(self) -> "Task":
        """
        Retrieves Task object and sets status of Task in database to "in progress" (1)

        :raises AlreadyUnderEvaluationError: If trying to pop a tasks that is already being processed  (i.e. if a race
        condition occurs if the queue is processed in parallel)
        """
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT _ROWID_ from tasks WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1")
        oid = cur.fetchall()[0][0].__str__()
        self.mark_running(oid, id(self))

        cur.execute("SELECT owner, task FROM tasks WHERE _ROWID_ = ?", oid)
        record = cur.fetchall()[0]
        if record[0] != id(self):
            raise AlreadyUnderEvaluationError

        task = Task.from_dict(json.loads(record[1]))
        task.oid = oid
        return task

    def peek(self) -> "Task":
        """
        Retrieves Task object without changing its status in the queue
        """
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * from tasks ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1")
        record = cur.fetchall()[0]
        oid = record[0].__str__()
        task = Task.from_dict(json.loads(record[1]), validate=False)
        task.oid = oid
        return task

    def print(self, n: int = 10) -> None:
        """
        Print an overview of the queue

        :param n: number of tasks to preview
        :type n: int
        """
        assert isinstance(n, int) and n > 0
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT status, task from tasks ORDER BY priority LIMIT ?", (str(n), ))
        records = cur.fetchall()
        for record in records:
            print(f"[{record[0]}] {Task.from_dict(json.loads(record[1]))}")

    def mark_pending(self, oid: int) -> None:
        """
        Mark the operation with the _ROWID_ `oid` as "pending" (0)

        :param oid: ID of the task to mark
        :type oid: int
        """
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE tasks SET status = 0, owner = NULL where _ROWID_ = ?", (oid, ))
        self.con.commit()

    def mark_running(self, oid: int, owner: int) -> None:
        """Mark the operation with the _ROWID_ `oid` as "running" (1). The "owner" Id is to ensure no two processes
        are trying to execute the same operation

        :param oid: ID of the task to mark
        :type oid: int
        :param owner: Id of the process that is handling the operation
        :type owner: int
        """
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE tasks SET status = 1, owner = ? where _ROWID_ = ?", (owner, oid))
        self.con.commit()

    def mark_done(self, oid: int) -> None:
        """
        Mark the operation with the _ROWID_ `oid` as "done" (2)
        :param oid: ID of the task to mark
        :type oid: int
        """
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE tasks SET status = 2, owner = NULL where _ROWID_ = ?", (oid, ))
        self.con.commit()

    def mark_failed(self, oid: int) -> None:
        """
        Mark the operation with the _ROWID_ `oid` as "failed" (-1)

        :param oid: ID of the task to mark
        :type oid: int
        """
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE tasks SET status = -1, owner = NULL where _ROWID_ = ?", (oid, ))
        self.con.commit()

    def run(self) -> None:
        """Execute all pending tasks"""
        if self.n_pending < 1:
            logging.getLogger().warn("Queue is empty")

        while self.n_pending > 0:
            op = self.pop()
            op.run()
            self.mark_done(op.oid)


class AlreadyUnderEvaluationError(Exception):
    """This Task is already being processed by a different worker"""
    pass
```

### A demo in pytest

```
import tasks
import pytest

def test_TaskQueue(tmp_path):
    """TaskQueue can queue and execute tasks"""
    src = tmp_path.joinpath("foo")
    src.touch()

    q = tasks.TaskQueue(tmp_path.joinpath("qcp.db"))
    q.put(tasks.CopyTask(src, tmp_path.joinpath("copied_file")))
    q.run()
    assert tmp_path.joinpath("copied_file").is_file()
    q.put(tasks.MoveTask(tmp_path.joinpath("copied_file"), tmp_path.joinpath("moved_file")))
    q.run()
    assert not tmp_path.joinpath("copied_file").is_file()
    assert tmp_path.joinpath("moved_file").is_file()
    q.put(tasks.DeleteTask(tmp_path.joinpath("moved_file")))
    q.run()
    assert not tmp_path.joinpath("moved_file").is_file()
    assert src.is_file()
```

p.s.: I am aware that I am importing `logging` for a single log call, but I plan to include more extensive logging in the future

Comment: `-> "Task"` works with quotes in place?

Comment: Yes but i think its a fairly recent thing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458470/should-you-put-quotes-around-type-annotations-in-python

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sometimes, Python is a bit messy, I think. Not pythonic. Looks more like a workaround than a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall your code is pretty clean.

### Abstract class

There are a few different ways to do this. You can explicitly use the `abc` stuff, but the simpler thing to do is in your abstract methods (e.g. `run`), raise a `NotImplementedError` - at the `Task` level, not just `KillTask`. Then classes like `KillTask` that are effectively abstract children simply omit the implementation.

### Enums

Python needs help when it comes to the type system. It's good that you're using type hints. You can help it out a little more by using a formal enum for the numbers in `from_dict`. Read here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

### Prepared statements

The series of functions beginning with `n_pending` should really only be one function. This is the perfect use case for prepared statements. Make that `status` number a parameter.

### Don't conflate purpose

`TaskQueue.print` really does two things - a fetch and a print. You should probably separate these.

### sqlite autocommit

From the brief Google I did, sqlite operates in autocommit mode by default. I don't think any of the commits you've done are necessary.

### Implicit cursors

It shouldn't be necessary to explicitly get those cursors. You can iterate on the return value of `fetchall`.